# Issue with download.file() in R. Odd url?

Tags: r

I'm looking at at DataCarpentries page [here](https://datacarpentry.org/r-raster-vector-geospatial/01-raster-structure.html) that is throwing an error from the [setup.R](https://github.com/datacarpentry/r-raster-vector-geospatial/blob/main/episodes/setup.R) file on their GitHub repo. On line 33 we see this:

```
dest <- tempfile()

download.file("https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_graticules_all.zip",
                  dest, mode = "wb")
```

The url is odd looking (to me), but correct (e.g., I can save the file from a browser). And the data are binary so `mode="wb"` seems correct. But the call to `download.file` throws an error and gives a dreaded '500 Internal Server Error' warning. I've tried using different methods, e.g., `method="curl"` downloads a text file that reads

"There has been a critical error on your website.
Learn more about debugging in WordPress."

Is this a matter of switching to a finer-grained approach using `url`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request that URL you get a 302 response, which means that the request is redirected.  Using the "Network" section of a browser's Developer Tools, you find that the final link is `https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/physical/ne_110m_graticules_all.zip`.  I have confirmed that `download.file()` works correctly with this link.